# How to add project in sonarqube?

Tags: automated-testing, static-testing

I successfully configured sonarqube locally and created users. But I am not getting how to add projects for code review in it. I am using it for the first time so don't have much idea about it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a project, you just have to run an analysis on it.  See the docs here: [Analysing with SonarQube Runner](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner).

Comment: I know this is an old post but if some context to the information contained within the link could be given it would be appreciated.

Comment: Sure thing, but what kind of context are you looking for?  Also, the link appears to be out of date - here's the new one: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Source+Code

Comment: Yes there was a recommended edit your which brought me here. As for context, explaining the product and what it does will typically allow the user to Google for a new link.